# enable a2enmod rewrite in dockerfile but the .htaccess does not work

Tags: docker, apache, .htaccess

I write Dockerfile and enable rewrite mode. Then I tried to edit etc/apache2/apache2.conf. But the rewrite mode does not work. Thank you.

Dockerfile

```
    FROM ubuntu:20.04
    ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
    RUN apt update
    RUN apt install apache2 -y
    RUN a2enmod rewrite
    RUN apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4 -y
```

...

.htaccess

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ abc/profile.php?mb_url=$1
```

...

etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem is solved by

edit `000-default.conf`:

```
   <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

copy the file to Docker

```
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```